# Optimize Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below, I am pulling a list of managers names that have had activity since 2023-01-01. The managers name comes from tblSAP and then I am joining to tblUsers2 to look for activity. In most cases the managers name is in the Supervisor or Level6 field BUT it could also be in Level5, 7 or 8 thus the multiple 'OR' conditions. This query is pulling the correct data back but takes around 90 seconds to run. tblUsers2 has 1.9 million rows and growing daily. My question is can this be optimized to run quicker? I am not sure what is going on in the background but am wondering if after the first occurrence of a managers name being found in tblUsers2 it can move on to the next manager? Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

```
DECLARE
@StartDate AS Datetime
SET @StartDate = '2023-01-01'

SELECT Last + ', ' + First AS Manager_Name
FROM tblSAP
INNER JOIN tblUsers2 U2 ON Last + ', ' + First = U2.Supervisor OR
    (Last + ', ' + First = Level6) OR
    (Last + ', ' + First = Level5) OR
    (Last + ', ' + First = Level7) OR
    (Last + ', ' + First = Level8)
WHERE U2.ExtractDate >= @StartDate AND (Title LIKE '%manager%') AND (Title LIKE '%operations%') OR (Job_Desc LIKE '%manager%') AND (Job_Desc LIKE '%operations%') 
GROUP BY Last, First
ORDER BY Last, First;
```

Comment: Look at the execution plan. What indexes do you have?

Comment: That clause on your column `Title` isn't going to be SARGable, and neither is your `ON`. The *real* problem appears to be the design and data; only after fixing that can you write a performant query.

Comment: What is SARGable? There is nothing I can do about the table design and data. I'm just trying to work with what I have. Thanks.

Comment: is your OR really correct? it would remove the date selection altogether

Comment: `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` (please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 )

Comment: siggemannen, thanks for pointing my OR mistake. After correcting it my query now runs in 45 seconds.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, i.e. provide a [mcve].

Comment: Some of your challenges are coming from a less than ideal design. You appear to have violated 1NF with repeating groups. That is the term for things like Level5, Level6, Level7 etc. That should likely be a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only select a name from the table `tblSAP`, you do not need to do an INNER JOIN to the table `tblsUser`, which could result in 1.9 million rows.

You only need to know if a user exist, so doing this might work (untested):

NOTE:

- added extra `()` arround the `OR` part (two times!)
- the EXISTS will sop searching the `tblUsers` when at least 1 user is found.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Datetime = '20230101'

SELECT 
   Last + ', ' + First AS Manager_Name
FROM tblSAP
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM  tblUsers2 U2 
    WHERE 
       Last + ', ' + First IN (U2.Supervisor, Level5, Level6, Level7, Level8)
       AND U2.ExtractDate >= @StartDate 
       AND (
              (Title LIKE '%manager%') AND (Title LIKE '%operations%') OR 
              (Job_Desc LIKE '%manager%') AND (Job_Desc LIKE '%operations%')
           ) 
  )
ORDER BY Last, First;
```

Comment: This solution works great! I learn something new everytime I visit this site. Thanks Luuk!

Comment: The manager/operations logic looks wrong with the `OR` only in the middle and no parentheses around the groups. Also cleaned up the Supervisor/Level expressions. But otherwise this is trending the right way.

Comment: It looks wrong (maybe), but it is not wrong.   For better readability you might need to add extra `()`  to make it: `(
              ((Title LIKE '%manager%') AND (Title LIKE '%operations%')) OR 
              ((Job_Desc LIKE '%manager%') AND (Job_Desc LIKE '%operations%'))
           ) `

Comment: `OR` in SQL is weird, and I think the parentheses, at least around the AND pairs, are probably mandatory here. Without them, the logic works like this: `( (Title LIKE '%manager%' AND Title LIKE '%operations%') OR Job_Desc LIKE '%manager%') AND Job_Desc LIKE '%operations%'` And even then, it seems odd to expect BOTH manager and operations in the same title, where maybe ALL of the conditional operators should be `OR`.

Comment: TITLE LIKE both manager **and** operations?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: This works, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/PWoQFxC1

Comment: @jarlh See, for example, this list: https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/finding-a-job/operations-job-titles  Only number 4 `Operations manager` would apply , and not the `Project manager`  or the `Operations coordinator`.

Comment: For clarification, Manager and Operations are both in the title and Job Desc but there can be other words as well such as Senior Operations Manager or Manager Operations Entertainment. That is why I am searching that way.